# recursive list in python

Tags: python, list, recursion

a simple question:

how to make a recursive list in python like this:

This is the input: A , B , C , D

The desired output:

```
              A | A>B | A>B>C | A>B>C>D
```

I tried this code:

```
line = "A, B , C , D"
line = line.split(',')

for i in range(len(line)):
    for j in range(i,len(line)):
             c=q+line[j]
             q=c+'>'
    c=c+'|'
```

but I came with a list like this:

```
'A > B > C > D > B > C > D > C > D|'
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why are so many people using range(len(iterable))
An iterable, by definition, had a __iter__ method which ends the iteration for us, so why coding like years and years ago?
Just saying...

Comment: @Apero Offer your solution which doesn't use `range`.

Comment: Just have a look to Roman solution below.
I was mostly talking about the first range, not the second one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's generator which gives you output you need. Performance-wise it's faster than double join, it's O(N) instead ot O(N^2)

```
>>> def getstr(s):
...     a = [x for x in s]
...     res = None
...     for x in a:
...         if not res: res = x
...         else: res = " > ".join([res, x])
...         yield res
>>>
>>> print " | ".join(getstr("ABCD"))
'A | A > B | A > B > C | A > B > C > D'
```

Comment: +1 I like this solution as it reuses previously created strings.

Comment: By the way, the first time I've seen the code which may use `ireduce` (iterator analog of traditional reduce).

Comment: String joining is technically `O(N)` in the length of the strings, not just their number, since the memory for all of the characters needs to be copied. So this algorithm is probably `O(N^2)` as well. A further improvement: `a = [x for x in s]` is unnecessary, uses `list(s)` or just iterate over the string directly (or use a `split` call to get a list of letters from a comma separated string, like the questioner asked about).

Comment: Profiling your and my solution, yours is indeed faster. +1 from me.

Comment: @Blckknght But the strings that he reuses are needed and yielded. In our sulutions we glue strings with `>` from the very beginning. If @Roman solution is `O(n^2)` then ours are `O(n^3)`.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this?

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

a = [c for c in 'ABCD']
result = ' | '.join ('>'.join (a [:x + 1] ) for x in range (len (a) ) )
print (result)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> s = 'A , B , C , D'
>>> L = map(str.strip, s.split(','))
>>> L
['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
>>> ' | '.join('>'.join(L[:i]) for i in range(1,len(L)+1))
'A | A>B | A>B>C | A>B>C>D'
```